# Cron job to run every 2 days in Cpanel

Tags: cron, cpanel

I'm looking for a way to create a cron job which should be **run every 2 days**. I mean it should run on the August 16, August 18, August 20, August 22, August 24, August 26, August 28 and so on. Note that today is **August 14**.

I have tried several scripts including `0 0 */2 * *  myscript.php`.
It turns out that `0 0 */2 * *  myscript.php` only run execute every 2nd day of every month according to http://cronchecker.net/. This is obviously NOT what I'm looking for. 
Any idea please? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following

```
0 0 2-30/2 * * myscript.php
```

This should work for you, as it runs every even day of the month

Comment: A bit close to what I'm looking for. Thanks